# Recurring Payment IPN variables confusion

Tags: magento2, paypal, recurring, increment-id, ipn

I have created subscription type of products in **Magento 2.2.5 CE**. And when i tried to purchase subscription type product( recurring payment type) paypal returns three IPNs.

- 'txn_type' = **cart/express_checkout(some times)**
- 'txn_type' = **recurring_payment_profile_created**
- 'txn_type' = **recurring_payment**

The first one contains '**invoice**' - magento's '**increment_id**' but other two don't.

Instead they contains '**rp_invoice_id**'. My question is how can I decide that all three IPNs are for the same order?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per I know there should be `recurring_payment_id` in your IPN response and It should be the same for the same profile.

Comment: yes there is `recurring_payment_id` in `recurring_payment` IPN but it is not there in `cart/express_checkout` IPN.